# Counting readmissions based on encounter in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

***sorry all just provided the correct data I"m retrieving based on query.

I'm looking for readmissions based on admit date. Any ptID with an admit date within 30 days of the previous admit date grouped by encounter. Take min admit date per encounter.  Let's say for the month of April/may based on my data below.  Many questions out there like this but they do not have multiple encounterID's. I also know there is an issue with the dates as a parameter.

I have the following data in my table;

```
    encounter       PtID        admit               discharge
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    V00018357259    M00104410   4/12/17 8:36 AM     NULL
    V00018357259    M00104410   4/12/17 8:36 AM     4/12/17 1:55 PM
    V00018362040    M00104410   4/13/17 4:38 PM     NULL
    V00018362040    M00104410   4/13/17 5:49 PM     NULL
    V00018362040    M00104410   4/13/17 11:04 PM    4/13/17 6:01 PM
    V00018362040    M00104410   4/13/17 11:04 PM    4/14/17 11:30 AM
    V00018408554    M00104410   5/3/17 9:51 AM      NULL
    V00018406101    M00104410   5/3/17 10:12 AM     NULL
```

Would like to receive the following as output:

```
    EncounterID   PtID         Admit             Readmission       DaySpan
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    V00018357259  M00104410    4/12/17 8:36 AM   4/13/17 4:38 PM     1 
    V00018357259  M00104410    4/12/17 8:36 AM   5/3/17 9:51 AM      21 
    V00018357259  M00104410    4/12/17 8:36 AM   5/3/17 10:12 AM     21
    V00018362040  M00104410    4/13/17 4:38 PM   5/3/17 9:51 AM      20
    V00018362040  M00104410    4/13/17 4:38 PM   5/3/17 10:12 AM     20
    V00018408554  M00104410    5/3/17 9:51 AM    5/3/17 10:12 AM     0
```

I have the current query

```
select  
    av.patient_id, 
    av.encounter, 
    av.admit_date, 
    av1.admit_date as readmission,
    datediff(d, av.admit_date, av1.admit_date) as dayspan
from 
    adt_visit av
left join 
    adt_visit av1 on av1.patient_id = av.patient_id
where 
    (datediff(d, av.admit_date, av1.admit_date) > 0)
    and (datediff(d, av.admit_date, av1.admit_date) <= 30)
    and av.admit_date >'4/1/2017' and av.admit_date < '4/30/2017'
    and av.patient_id = 'M00104410'  
group by
     av.patient_id
     ,av.encounter
     , av.admit_date
     , av1.admit_date
```

Which is producing this:

```
     PtID       Encounter       Admit               Readmission       Dayspan
     ------------------------------------------------------------------------
     M00104410  V00018357259    4/12/17 8:36 AM     4/13/17 4:38 PM     1
     M00104410  V00018357259    4/12/17 8:36 AM     4/13/17 5:49 PM     1
     M00104410  V00018357259    4/12/17 8:36 AM     4/13/17 11:04 PM    1
     M00104410  V00018357259    4/12/17 8:36 AM     5/3/17 9:51 AM      21
     M00104410  V00018357259    4/12/17 8:36 AM     5/3/17 10:12 AM     21
     M00104410  V00018362040    4/13/17 4:38 PM     5/3/17 9:51 AM      20
     M00104410  V00018362040    4/13/17 4:38 PM     5/3/17 10:12 AM     20
```

Can anyone help?  Thanks!

Comment: What is your database (RDBMS) ?

Comment: Also, you're referencing two tables, but I'm only seeing the structure of one of them. Can you provide both?

Comment: SQL server db. I reference av1 as a temp table.  It is not a physical table.